# День рождения или День рожденья?

Tags: орфография

Когда речь идет о празднике, как правильнее писать: День рожденИя или День рожденЬя?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно: **день рождения**. -ЬЕ- разг.

Comment: В этом словосочетании очень многие делают ошибки. Надо ставить вопрос: день (чего?) рождения. И еще, как правильно написано в ответе Соан, пишутся оба слова с маленькой буквы. Хотя мня так и тянет иногда написать большую, чтобы подчеркнуть значительность события.

Comment: Надо же! А я тоже думала, что "День" с большой)))) Эх, принижают они великий праздник))))))

Comment: На открытках встречаются оба варианта :))))

Comment: Текст на открытках не всегда правильный. Я бы тоже написала День (с большой буквы), но правило гласит обратное.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно говорить **день рождения**.

Comment: Голосуем за «день рождения»?